# Creating sql for attribute with constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT,
    Post TEXT,
    Age INT LEN<68
    )
```

How do i create that `Post` attribute where the constraint must be either Manager or clerk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not enforce check constraints.  This leaves you with three options:

1. You can create an `enum` with two values, `'manager'` and `'clerk'`.
2. You can create a reference table that has two rows, and use a foreign key reference.
3. You can create a trigger to check the values.

By the way, this line:

```
Age INT LEN<68
```

is not syntactically correct.

Comment: or a before insert trigger?

Comment: @Steve . . . No.  MySQL does not enforce CHECK constraints.